# Um caso estranho na gerência de um projeto. Qual posição tomar?

Tags: projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos

A questão é relativo à gerência de projeto, onde foi esta a melhor (talvez única) forma de expor a minha dúvida perante à situação. Concordo que ficou um pouco extensa, porém não encontrei outra forma de focalizar a mesma.

Vamos lá:

A empresa está vendo um novo projeto (trata-se de um sistema de médio porte), e em reuniões aconteceu o seguinte:

Para este projeto foram designado dois programadores e um analista, onde neste caso  o analista tem menos experiência do que os dois programadores (que seria eu e outro). Em determinada pauta, estavam sendo discutidas as tecnologias a serem utilizadas e como seriam as camadas, arquiteturas, etc.... deste sistema. O analista fez algumas sugestões. O outro programador (este com mais experiência do que eu) logo interferiu com argumentações técnicas mostrando que não seria uma boa escolha e nisso o analista não aceitando, a reunião passou em torno dos 40 min a mais do que o previsto.

Em novas reuniões o programador trouxe documentações e mais explicações sugerindo um modelo de arquitetura e outros pontos também, como fluxo do GIT, etc... que seriam bons e previsto a todo o projeto (nesta parte percebi que realmente eram boas sugestões) e o analista novamente relutou, onde estranhamente sem nenhuma argumentação técnica conseguiu aprovação do gerente do projeto que apresentava o novo projeto. Uma semana depois este programador recebeu uma advertência oral (nada formal, mas diante da equipe) sobre ele estar empecilhando o projeto com suas posições, etc...

Hoje, passado uns quatro meses, o sistema está com uma arquitetura proposta pelo analista com regras de negócio um pouco em uma camada designada no PHP, outro pouco no AngularJS. O sistema foi feito utilizando AngularJS. O angular em si tem uma parte para roteamento, mas mesmo assim existem algumas páginas em PHP pois o analista achou mais "fácil" para fazer.

Na produção está sendo utilizado um SGBD e no desenvolvimento um outro SGBD diferente (outra escolha do analista). Cada desenvolvedor tem uma versão diferente da modelagem do banco, onde um arquivo .sql é enviado referente à tarefa e nenhum destes tem acesso ao sistema rodando por completo e muito menos à modelagem da base, pois tudo é independente e focado somente ao analista.

Todas as tomadas de decisões técnicas hoje é focada somente por este analista e embora já apareceram erros de até R$1.000,00 reais em comissões (partes do sistema já está em uso, pois trata-se de um sistema interno), e o foco da gerencia continua a dar toda relevância técnica para este. Assim como todas as implementações mais complexas, do tipo que seriam interessante opiniões, tomadas de decisões em equipe, debates, etc este faz tudo sozinho. Outro dia ao ver novamente este programador a corrigir de um erro em uma tela, o analista simplesmente meio que "jogou na cara" dizendo que ele era o analista e que tomava todas as decisões que seria daquela forma e pronto.

Visto o contexto descrito acima, e levando em consideração que financeiramente a empresa paga(R$) de forma razoável, me vem os seguintes pontos:

1. Necessito de opiniões, feedbacks, críticas, elogios, sugestões, formas de pensar, etc.... no geral sobre este contexto.
2. Vale a pena investir carreira em uma empresa que tem um setor de desenvolvimento assim? (Hoje existe apenas três projetos médios na empresa, contando com este)

Na minha opinião está no mínimo bizarro a situação, mas gostaria de opiniões e experiências focalizando sobre uma posição a ser tomada diante da situação. Estes dois pontos que citei considero importantes.

**OBS:** Está certo que não está 100% digamos de acordo com as regras daqui, porém sendo o tempo de vida desta dúvida limitada, são válidas as considerações, ou de repente um "váculo" até que alguém com maior experiência leia esta pergunta.

Comment: não fui eu que votei negativo, mas, essa pergunta é offtopic para o site. Acho que para este tipo de dúvida, o forum do guj (guj.com.br) se encaixa melhor. Boa sorte!

Comment: Valeu, não tinha pensado ir no guj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na minha visão, existem respostas simples e complicadas, porque a coisa ta meio subjetiva ai. Mas, vou tentar ser objetivo.

**1 - O que você quer na vida, continua sendo o que você quer independente de um projeto em particular.**

É o seguinte, de cara, sobre ficar ou não no projeto. Foque no que você quer, se quer continuar, continua, se não quer começa a procurar outro. Isso vai envolver se está aprendendo alguma coisa, se está precisando do dinheiro e um monte de coisas pessoais, simplesmente olhe por fora do projeto e pense no que você quer.

**2 - Uma tribo não pode ter 3 caciques.**

Rapaz, de forma bem direta, se o poder de decisão é do Analista, então a decisão  é do analista e ponto. Não estou dizendo que você tem que concordar, estou dizendo que em tudo na vida, uma decisão tem que ser tomada e nas empresas, os papeis servem para isso. O que você pode fazer já está sendo feito, mostrar outros pontos de vista, mas, no final a pessoa que tem o poder de decisão pode simplesmente decidir por não fazer, isso não é necessariamente uma afronta ou alguma coisa ruim, ele tem  a responsabilidade e pode decidir, você pode discordar, mas se decidir permanecer no projeto, tem que aceitar que nem sempre suas sugestões serão aceitas e que faz parte da vida profissional aceitar bem a decisão alheia. Isso não vale para aspectos éticos, se  lhe pedirem pra roubar, continua sendo roubo mesmo se for seu chefe ou analista. Se acabou a ética, então procure um lugar melhor.

**3 - A sua verdade nem sempre é a verdade.**

Muitas vezes, estamos tão focados na nossa visão do problema que esquecemos de olhar com carinho a visão dos outros e algumas pessoas tem uma tendência perder o foco sobre o que é importante e acabam focando simplesmente em ganhar a discussão. Na minha visão, se vocês ainda estão tentando convencer o Analista (que ja decidiu) sobre a arquitetura, ou estão fazendo errado ou estão perdendo o tempo do projeto discutindo algo que ja foi decidido, tem 4 meses de operação e que não vai levar a lugar nenhum porque é muito pouco provavel uma refatoração deste tamanho em um projeto que está em produção a 4 meses. Então, meu conselho é repensar o posicionamento de vocês que pode realmente estar atrapalhando e não ajudando. Isso não impede você de continuar conversando ou propondo outras melhorias, apenas mude o foco, ou mude a abordagem. Se você está tão frustrado porque nunca é ouvido, ainda está fazendo o que la?

**4 - O velho caso dos números.**

Vocês tem alguma métrica para dizer se o que foi adotado é bom ou ruim? o sistema tem bugs? falhas de segurança? quantos bugs ocorrem em teste? quantos passam para produção? No lugar pegar emails esporádicos sobre problemas ou valores pagos indevidamente por causa de bugs, defina seu processo de software e operação e comece a acompanhar os números. Faça um rastreamento das funcionalidades com mais problemas e qualifique quais tipos de falhas estão gerando os problemas, com números fica mais fácil decidir por soluções definitivas e não faça disso uma caça as bruxas, quando tiver esse tipo de relatório, leve uma solução antes para ser testada o lugar de levantar o culpado. Todos já sabem de quem é a culpa, mesmo que seja sua ou do analista, não interessa e não vai melhorar a vida de vocês nem o software.

**5 - Software funcional é a medida primária de progresso.** 
Essa frase não é minha e eu mesmo muitas vezes tive que repetir ela para mim mesmo para não estrangular algum cliente. Eu tenho uma formaçãoo técnica e como tal, gosto de fazer coisas técnicas bem feitas, não gosto de caminhos aparentemente errados. Acumula débito técnico e vai contra o que está nas minhas veias. Mas, o mundo não é perfeito, nem seu software vai ser e se você não conseguir colocar ele em produção, na verdade, você falhou muito mais do que se fizer ele diferente do que imagina. O que quero dizer é que o sistema está em funcionamento, então você tem que começar a equilibrar as coisas entre preciosismo técnico e satisfação do cliente. Então, uma pergunta muito mais importante depois de 4 meses é: O seu cliente está satisfeito com o software? Se sim, maravilha, melhore ele. Se não, encontre o porque, caso contrário, independente da arquitetura e de todo o brilhantismo que possa ser proposto, vocês vão falhar.

Se vocês usam um processo ágil de software, então leia:
http://www.manifestoagil.com.br/

E coloque um pouco mais desses valores na sua vida.

Comment: Concordo que exista algo subjetivo, mas não encontrei outra forma de expor a dúvida. Realmente eu necessitava da opinião de alguém com (vamos assim dizer) uma "visão maior" sobre estes assuntos, como a sua, por exemplo. Valeu!

Comment: Foi feito uma tentativa no inicio do projeto por este analista em utilizar o scrum, porém foi utilizado de forma "engessada" do tipo seguindo rigidamente cada passo, sem retirar e nem colocar nada. Não deu certo e hoje a "metodologia" é baseada em necessidade dos utilizadores e passado para funcionalidades.

Comment: Resumindo, "estamos sem processo de software". Tentativas são assim, falham, escolhe outra, falha, escolhe outra, falha, escolhe outra e assim vai,... Tente implementar algo parecido com Scrum solo, sem desrespeitar o que está definido e mostre quais são as vantagens. Se der certo, a adoção vai ser natural. E outro conselho, pare de dizer o Analista tentou isso ou aquilo, parece mais uma esquiva da responsabilidade de fazer parte do projeto do que uma resposta, comece a dizer Nós fizemos, afinal, você é parte do processo. Pense como seria se você estivesse no lugar do analista e lesse isso.